# How to send page to publishing queue at the top of the list using event handler?

Tags: publishing, content-manager

We have an event handler that publishes the certain type of pages to the different publications (we have the list of publications) and its working as expected but the problem here is the order in which it sends to the publishing queue.
Yes it will send the pages as ordered in the list but the original tcm value in which we are only replacing the pub id is sent at the last of publicaition.
For example
when we send a page (tcm:5-1234-64)

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<RepositoryLocalObject, PublishEventArgs>(OnPageItemPre, EventPhases.Initiated);

private void OnPageItemPre(RepositoryLocalObject item, PublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase){
    List <int>pubIDList = new List(){31,32,34,35};
    List<IdentifiableObject> itemToPublish = new List<IdentifiableObject>();
    foreach (var pubId in pubIdList)
    {
       itemToPublish.Add(item.Session.GetObject($"tcm:{pubId}-{pg.Id.ItemId}-64"));
    }
    
    PublishEngine.Publish(itemToPublish, args.PublishInstruction, publicationTargets, args.Priority.Value);
}
```

result: order in which the pages are published.

```
tcm:31-1234-64
tcm:32-1234-64
tcm:33-1234-64
tcm:34-1234-64
tcm:5-1234-64
```

how can we put tcm:5-1234-64 at the top of the queue?

Comment: Binod , just to clarify publication ID 5 is the parent and ( 31,32,33,34) or the child publication.

Comment: You may try to utilize the priority feature here. Set the priority to high for parent publication (ID: 5) and for the rest, you can keep it normal.

Comment: @anandNS yes id 5 is the parent and ( 31,32,33,34) these the specific child publications

Comment: @SayantanBasu you mean setting the priority in which it needs to send to the publishing queue?

Comment: PublishEngine.Publish API - your last parameter you can control how you want to publish as @SayantanBasu mentioned, like PublishPriority.Normal or PublishPriority.High

Comment: The thing i noticed is that after the list of tcm are send to publish and then it sends automatically the id : 5 page to the queue. As the PublishPriority must be the same for all publishing pages so this wont work

Comment: I really don't know what use case you are trying to achieve using the event system handler to publish? can you update your question to clarify a bit more detail?

Comment: when we publish certain pages from tridion then we are trying to publish these page in other publications too (we got the list of pub id) thats our goal but the order that it sends to the publishing queue is not correct cause it sends the parent page to the last of publishing queue.

Comment: Could you add the original in your script. And then remove the last item (which would be the item originally published). Check what happens When publishing multiple pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Publish Transactions you are adding in your event handler are *before* the original Publish Transaction, because your event handler triggers on the “Initiated” phase. That is: *before* the original Publish action executes.

If you want to add them after, you should subscribe to the “Processed” phase.

Comment: thanks @Rick its the perfect solution for me.